# Why CDI not working?

Tags: java, glassfish, cdi, jersey-2.0

I have the next rest service:

```
@ApplicationPath("geo")
@Path("weather")
public class MainResource extends Application {

    @Inject
    private MainDep dep;

    @GET
    public String printGotIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("propaganda")
    public String printPropaganda() {
        return dep.printPropaganda();
    }
}
```

MainDep dependency code:

```
public class MainDep {
    public String printPropaganda() {
        return "Interesting enterprise";
    }
}
```

When I trying to use resource on following url: host:port/root/geo/weather GlassFish threw a javax.servlet.ServletException:

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.app.weather.rs.MainResource threw exception
root cause`
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
    1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=MainDep,parent=MainResource,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,22064320)
    root cause
    org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=MainDep,parent=MainResource,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're mixing JAX-RS Application + JAX-RS resource class in one class and on top of that you're adding a CDI injection into the mix.

Try to separate the JAX-RS Application from JAX-RS resource, like:

```
@ApplicationPath("geo")
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MainResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Path("weather")
public class MainResource {

    @Inject
    private MainDep dep;

    @GET
    public String printGotIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("propaganda")
    public String printPropaganda() {
        return dep.printPropaganda();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()` not needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@RequestScoped` to your class.

Comment: I can't deploy my application to glassfish 4 if I add `@RequestScoped` to MainResource class. Error text: `An error has occurred
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref<ContainerRequest>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref<ContainerRequest>, ProcessingProviders)]. Please see server.log for more details.`

Comment: I think @RequestScoped is by default so it would not be needed

Comment: There is no default in CDI.